# Python subprocess block

Tags: python, subprocess, wait, blocking

I'm having a problem with the module subprocess; I'm running a script from Python:

```
subprocess.Popen('./run_pythia.sh', shell=True).communicate()
```

and sometimes it just blocks and it doesn't finish to execute the script. Before I was using `.wait()`, but I [switched to `.communicate()`](http://dcreager.net/2009/08/06/subprocess-communicate-drawbacks/). Nevertheless the problem continues.

First the script compiles a few files, then it execute into a file:

`run_pythia.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l walltime=1:00:00

./compile.sh
./exec > resultado.txt
```

`compile.sh`:

```
O=`find ./ -name "*.o" | xargs`

# LOAD cernlib2005
module load libs/cernlib/2005

# Compile and Link
FC=g77
CERNLIBPATH="-L/software/local/cernlib/2005/lib -lpacklib"

$FC call_pyth_mix.f analise_tt.f $O $CERNLIBPATH -o exec
```

Comment: Do you need to interact with the process? Or are you simply reading the output?  You should use `.communicate()` as it'll prevent any deadlock issues.  However, if you need to interact with the process by writing to stdin and reading from stderr/stdout, that's a whole new ball of wax.

Answer (score 3):

Is the script you execute, is `run_pythia.sh` guaranteed to finish executing? If not, you might not want to use blocking methods like `communicate()`. You might want to look into interacting with the `.stdout`, `.stderr`, and `.stdin` file handles of the returned process handle yourself (in a non-blocking manner).

Also, if you still want to use `communicate()`, you need to have had passed `subprocess.PIPE` object to `Popen`'s constructor arguments.

Read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) on the module for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to do a trace on it:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```